# Is there any way to automatically set the all layouts to support for both RTL and LTR direction types of languages in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext, textview

I am stuck to change the language of the whole `android` application. I found a way to set the `strings` into `strings-languagecode` in `values` directory and `android:supportsRtl="true"` in manifest file, it is good for changing the value of the `text fields` and their direction `LTR` and `RTL` automatically but I am getting the problem in `EditText` field because it's direction needs to be changed and set by the Java code for every `xml` file. Is there any way to set the direction of the `EditText` automatically in whole application with minimum effort? Please note I have minimum `api level 15` in my project.

Comment: You don't need to change direction of edittext(or any view) programmatically, Android do this for you when you specify supportsRtl true. You must have missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try these methods to change RTL or LTR layout directions.

For **RIGHT TO LEFT:**

ex. locale : Arabic(ar), Hebrew(he);

```
private void setRtl(){
    String languageToLoad  = "ar"; // rtl language Arabic
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);  
    Locale.setDefault(locale); 
    
    Configuration config = new Configuration(); 
    config.locale = locale; 
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,  
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            //layout direction 
    Bidi b = new Bidi(languageToLoad,Bidi.DIRECTION_DEFAULT_RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
            b.isRightToLeft();
    //save current locale in SharedPreferences
    SharedPreferences languagepref = getSharedPreferences("language",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = languagepref.edit();
    editor.putString("languageToLoad",languageToLoad );
    editor.commit(); 

    startActivity(...);// refresh activity.
}
```

**For LEFT TO RIGHT:**

ex locale : English(en), Tamil(ta)., etc.

```
private void setLtr(){
   String languageToLoad  = "en"; // ltr language English
   Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);  
   Locale.setDefault(locale); 

   Configuration config = new Configuration(); 
   config.locale = locale; 
   getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,  
        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        //layout direction 
   Bidi b = new Bidi(languageToLoad, Bidi.DIRECTION_DEFAULT_LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
            b.isLeftToRight();
   //save current locale in SharedPreferences
   SharedPreferences languagepref = getSharedPreferences("language",MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = languagepref.edit();
   editor.putString("languageToLoad",languageToLoad );
   editor.commit(); 

   startActivity(...);// refresh activity.
```

}

Call these method to change RTL or LTR layout directions.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! You can add it to your theme in styles.xml and it will apply to all TextViews:

```
<item name="android:textDirection">locale</item>
```

Comment: textDirection required minimum api level 17 but i have minimum api level is 15. then what i need to do.

Comment: @singh.indolia Unfortunately, you'll have trouble supporting RTL in that version of Android. Full support only appeared in 4.2 (API level 17).

Comment: Yes @singh.indolia. I suggest you do it the programmatic way then.