# Force one build flavor RTL, and one build flavor LTR

Tags: android, locale, right-to-left

I have an application with 2 Build Flavors, "Israel" and "France".
I want to force, for each build flavor, the layout direction, for Israel to be RTL and for France to be LTR without considering the device language.
I checked all over the internet and didn't find anything about it.
What can i do?

Comment: Have you checked the following link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40859072/is-there-any-way-to-automatically-set-the-all-layouts-to-support-for-both-rtl-an

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the perfect library to force Locale in Android, works like a magic!

https://github.com/zeugma-solutions/locale-helper-android

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using Gradle `productFlavors` and then defining a "base" style in each.

First, add this to your app-level build.gradle file:

```
android {
    ...
    flavorDimensions "direction"
    productFlavors {
        left {
            dimension "direction"
        }
        right {
            dimension "direction"
        }
    }
}
```

Second, create two new directories under `app/src/`

- `app/src/left/res/values/`
- `app/src/right/res/values`

Then, inside each one, create a `styles.xml` file and add this style:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppThemeBase" parent="[put whatever you had as AppTheme's parent here]">
        <item name="android:layoutDirection">ltr</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

(Use `ltr` for the `left` productFlavor, and `rtl` for the `right` productFlavor.)

Finally, in your `app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`, change your `AppTheme` style to inherit from `AppThemeBase`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppThemeBase">
    ...
</style>
```

Now you should have build variants like `leftDebug`, `leftRelease`, `rightDebug`, and `rightRelease`. When you build `leftDebug` or `leftRelease`, everything will be left-to-right. When you build `rightDebug` or `rightRelease`, everything will be right-to-left.

Comment: Just realized you said you already had two flavors defined. You can of course swap out `app/src/left/res/values/` for `app/src/france/res/values/` (and same for right/israel) and the solution should still work for you.

Comment: This is not working for me, around 2 secs after the first Activity created all the views suddenly jump to the correct side and its only working in this activity, not on other activity.

Comment: Then either you have some other code interfering with layoutDirection, or you haven't applied my answer correctly. Did you make sure to create two new resource directories, each under the correct product flavor source set? Are you applying the layoutDirection theme to your activity? Do you have the style inheritance set up correctly?

Comment: Yes my friend, i did all of this correct, it just doesn't work with layoutDirection, must be something with Locale, i just found another answer that work so far, i'll check it further and update. thanks alot.